# How to force an <ENTER> in the code when inputting into a table rendered with rhandsontable in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm working with an input table rendered using `shiny` and `rhandsontable`. User has the ability to add columns with the click of an action button labeled "Add column". If the user inputs a value into the table without hitting the `<ENTER>` key first and goes straight to the action button and clicks, the table starts flashing (bouncing) without stop. But if the user inputs a value into the table, hits `<ENTER>` while still in the table, and then hits the action button, in this sequence, no problem. Users can't be trusted to always hit `<ENTER>` first before going to the action button.

Is there a way to code an `<ENTER>` upon a click of the "Add column" action button, before executing the add column code? If this can be done, I assume it would go into the  `observeEvent(input$addCol...)` section of the code.

Below is reduced example code, except it doesn't have the bouncing problem. If someone could please explain if it's possible to force a behind-the-scenes `<ENTER>` or if there is otherwise a way to resolve this sort of bouncing problem. I've looked for circular dependencies in the full code this example derives from and there are none (so far that I see).

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
DF1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable1'),br(),
  actionButton("addCol", "Add column"),br(),
  uiOutput("delCol") 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTbl1 <- reactiveVal(DF1)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {uiTbl1(hot_to_r(input$hottable1))})
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTbl1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addCol, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,2))
    names(newCol) <- paste("Col", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable1)) + 1)
    uiTbl1(cbind(uiTbl1(), newCol))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Debouncing can help in this sort of situation. I would still like to see how to force an ENTER in R. For debouncing see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69251816/r-shiny-debounce-with-reactivevalues-and-observeevent-r-input-debounce

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. On my installation there is no flashing without hitting ENTER. There might be a circular reference which should be adressed instead of hitting ENTER programmatically. However, to answer the question: on windows you might want to check library([KeyboardSimulator](https://github.com/ChiHangChen/KeyboardSimulator)) and its function `keybd.press("Enter")` - make sure to install the latest GitHub version due to [this](https://github.com/ChiHangChen/KeyboardSimulator/issues/28). As an alternative this could be done [via JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41137833/9841389).

Comment: Just to be clear `library(KeyboardSimulator)` will only work on the host. If you have clients using another PC you'll need different solution. However, in general hitting ENTER programmatically seems unclean.

Comment: This example is simplified and doesn't have the issue. This is representative of the much more cumbersome code that does have the issue. I found no circular dependencies, but debouncing resolved this. Is there an automated way to find any circular dependencies, even a package, that does this? Sort of the way XLS highlights circular references for you.

Comment: The only package I'm aware of, that might help analyzing the issue is library([reactlog](https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/)). Not automated though.

Comment: I am now using `reactlog`, it's very helpful. I believe I have narrowed the problem down and can demonstrate the bouncing. Will repost the question, then delete this one later at some point.

Comment: I wouldn't delete this one. Maybe the above links will help someone else. Cheers

Comment: Here's a link to a question related to the above, an example where input table bouncing occurs and there is no circular dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173471/why-does-my-r-input-table-sometimes-start-bouncing-and-flashing-after-hitting-an